# FileHelpers and SQL Insert with SqlServerStorage class ---How to show errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, filehelpers

I am using the FileHelpers libraries to upload a CSV file to SQL Server.  I would like to present the user with a list of records which could not be uploaded do to errors.  I am setting the ErrorMode of the SqlServerStorage class to SaveAndContinue, however the InsertRecords method still throws an exception when one of the records violates a foriegn key constraint.  Is there a way to save this error and continue with the insert?

```
SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage(typeof(RouteRecord),ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString);
storage.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = FileHelpers.ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
storage.InsertRecords((RouteRecord[])Session["successfulRecordArray"]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that you have.. we don't know what your Class looks like so please post necessary code examples. also Foreign Key Constraint usually means that you are trying to Insert the same value twice or multiple times where only one of those values can be inserted..

Comment: I added the code.  The foreign key exception is happening because an attempt is being made to an add a record to a table where there is no corresponding record in a master table.

Comment: ok I was not aware of the MasterDetail Relationship anyway what is RouteRecord or where is it declared.. aslo one point you are getting typeof(RouteRecord) but inserting you are Casting ((RouteRecord[]) shouldn't that be Session["successfulRecordArray"].ToArray() Need to see how the things are truly defined.. looks like you may have a type issue going on here

Comment: It's not a type issue.  It's an issue with me understanding how the FileHelpers InsertRecord method behaves.  I'm tweaking the code to just iterate through the array and I'm doing my own error handling.

Comment: ok good luck.. if you still have issues repost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for FileHelpers 2.9.9, the [FileHelpers error handling](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_errorhandling.html) does not seem to have been implemented for the `DatabaseStorage` class which is the base class for `SqlServerStorage`.  I think the reason is probably, that the SQL statements are handled as in batches for performance reasons, so it is not possible to `catch` an individual record's error.

It would not be too difficult to add the missing error-handling by overriding `InsertRecords(Object[])`, but unfortunately `SqlServerStorage` is `sealed` and some of the helper routines are `internal`, so you'd end up having to copy several classes into your code.  (If you do this, make sure that you set `ExecuteInBatch` to false, so that each SQL statement gets processed individually - this will affect performance).

Alternatively, you could implement some check for foreign key violations (e.g., by enumerating `RouteRecord[]`) in a separate routine which is called before the `InsertRecords()` call, but this would not prevent errors occurring for other reasons.