# ErrorHandling in Filehelpers when using SqlStorage

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I provided record containing column with integer type, instead of reporting errors (as documented [here](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_errorhandling.html)) got `InvalidCastException` in method below (for filling records in storage):

```
protected void FillRecordOrder(object rec, object[] fields)
{
    OrdersVerticalBar record = (OrdersVerticalBar) rec;

    record.OrderDate = (DateTime) fields[0];
}
```

How to handle errors using SqlStorage in Filehelpers library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the contents of fields[0]? Are you saying it contains an integer? Then you need to convert it somehow to a DateTime. Something like:

```
protected void FillRecordOrder(object rec, object[] fields)
{
    OrdersVerticalBar record = (OrdersVerticalBar) rec;

    if (fields[0] == null)
      record.OrderDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    else if (fields[0] is DateTime)
      record.OrderDate = (DateTime)fields[0];
    else if (fields[0] is int)
    {
      DateTime baseDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
      DateTime newDate = baseDate.AddDays((int)fields[0]);
      record.OrderDate = newDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer is just an example, I want to catch all invalid values (when user has selected wrong column, I have SQL Select Query based on selected columns in combobox) in ErrorManager and output errors. But I think it'd be better to populate combobox with just Date columns (to choose from) than let the user search from all columns (on Document).

Comment: The best way of doing that might be to declare all the fields as `string` then and handle any conversion in FillRecordOrder. The advantage of `string` is that it never raises an `InvalidCastException` because every object has a `ToString()`.

Comment: Is it impossible to catch those errors using SqlServerStorage? In flat file I can just iterate through errors (foreach ErrorInfo err in engine.ErrorManager.Errors) and display every ConvertException (when ex. field is DateTime but value presented to it was different).

Comment: The FileHelpers error handling is not currently supported. See [this similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8908808/1077279).